# Why Can't I post here?

Tags: support, post-ban

I am getting this message and am new and don't know why-

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.

Comment: see the link. It explains it. Its wierd that you'd have that happen on a new account, or that you could post to ask.

Answer (score 6):

Upon having a closer look it really seems there's not a lot you can fix about this:

- Your answers on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/348675) don't really answer the question. There's also rarely need to post two answers on the same topic. We're not a forum and you can always edit your posts to add information. You've been told that by one user.
- Your answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/496006) also doesn't answer the question. The OP is asking how to change the boot screen, and you're telling them how they can get a Start menu in Windows 8. Also, you seem to be promoting your website for more great freeware tools and all kinds of shiny stuff. We generally frown upon self-promotion here, except where it's really relevant.
- Your answer on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/499007) didn't really provide a solution either. It was more of an unfactual comment about Vista having blue screens with drivers. You can post comments once you have 50 reputation.
- One of your two deleted questions literally was

  > Does anyone need a Software/Freeware for Windows 8?

  That's not even a real question. You should have checked our [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) about what kind of questions are considered on-topic.
- The other one was almost spam for your website, promoting a list of free tools, not really asking a question either.

All in all, I'd say the ban worked quite as expected. Normally we'd encourage you to fix your posts, as stated in the Meta question linked to in the error message you get, but there's not much to fix here. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Of your four answers, all have been deleted.

Of your three questions, 2 were deleted and 1 was migrated to meta (this one).

Your account has been blocked from posting because of low-quality contributions. This ban is permanent and cannot be manually reversed by a moderator.

> Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time: if you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again. The only way for the ban to be lifted is for you to convince the community that they should give you another chance...
>
> Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts! As noted above, down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled, formatted, and overly long or short? Then fix them!

Answer (score 3):

As your link clearly states:

> An [automatic filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system/60294#60294) is in place to ban questions and/or answers from IP addresses or accounts with a history of *extremely* poor posts.
>
> Once you have posted too many poorly-received questions or answers, you will be banned from posting more, and you will see the error message.

Basically, you've been IP banned.  If you're at a school or business (or even at home), it may be someone else there who has deserved the ban.  If it wasn't you making all the rubbish questions, you may be able to try again from a computer with a different internet connection.